# Firebase onDisconnect how to trigger other function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am reading firebase doc on `onDisconnect` but it didn't quite mention the operation i am looking for. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect

Goal: when a connection is disconnected, I want to run a function that updates other data that is not related to this connection data.

My code is below:

```
let PlayerRef = database.ref("/players");
let MessageRef = database.ref("/messages");
let con=playersRef.child(0).push('test');   
con.onDisconnect().remove(); // yes i want to remove that current connection
// BUT I also want to update the MessageRef that is 
//using the data in the "con", how can I acheive this???
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can attach an `onDisconnect()` handler to any location in your database and remove or write data to that location.

But realize that `onDisconnect()` works by sending the write operation to the Firebase servers up front. So you can write any value, as long as that value can be calculated on the client when you attach the `onDisconnect` listener.

Comment: i don't really get this. the data i am trying to update is not attached to the `.onDisconnect()` function though. basically I have `locA.onDisconnect().wantToUpdate(locB)

Comment: `onDisconnect` can be attached to any location, so `locB.onDisconnect().set(...)`

Comment: so generally speaking. the `.onDisconnect()` has no knowledge of what's been disconnected, other than detecting that something has been disconnected?

Comment: You seem to think that Firebase keeps a connection for each reference. It doesn't. A single client keeps (in most cases) a single open connection to the server. If that client disconnects, all `onDisconnect()` handlers from that client fire.

Answer (score 1):

With onDisconnect() you can trigger function inside remove():

```
    this.ref.onDisconnect().remove((err)=> {
        if (err) {
            console.error('could not establish onDisconnect event', err);
        }
    });
```

You most to add 'if(err)' inside because for some reason it's execute right when you active the connection, and actually worst - it's remove all the data in that link on firebase database.

better way to add trigger when firebase is disconnect is this:

```
    const Ref = new Firebase('...firebaseio.com');
    Ref.child('users/water').on('value', (data) {
        if (data.val() == true) {
            /* trigger when disconnected */
        } else {
           /* trigger when connected */
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentations `.remove` accepts a callback parameter. I believe you can utilize that. Like this:

```
con.onDisconnect().remove(() => {
  MessageRef.update(...);
});
```

Comment: I've just tried that. but it doesn't seem to work. the callback function is called regardless of whether connection is disconnected

Comment: could u post an example on how u did this? and update the question so other users can see what you've tried add test.

Comment: con.onDiscommect().remove(function(){
   MessageRef.set({message: "test"}); // this get inserted not on disconnect
});

Answer (score 0):

You can also have `onDisconnect()` write to a node that triggers a cloud function which then runs your "updates other data that is not related to this connection data" logic.

> If you want a function to trigger when the client disconnects, you'll have to set up the onDisconnect() on the client side, the have that write to a location that triggers a function to react to that event.

From a relevant discussion here: [Combine onDisconnect with Cloud Functions in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258156/combine-ondisconnect-with-cloud-functions-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.
It's even their in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

```
var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");//reference to a location in the database with the data as true. This will be read-only
connectedRef.on("value", (snap) => {
  if (snap.val() == true) {
//code for when we are connected
  } else {
    //update your data here
  }
});
```