# Combine onDisconnect with Cloud Functions in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Let's say a user can write to "rooms" and the values should remove when the user disconnects, I thought the cloud function code would look like this:

```
exports.Rooms = functions.database.ref('/rooms/{values}').onWrite(event => {
 if (!event.data.exists()){return}
   return db.ref('rooms/' + `${event.params.values}`).onDisconnect().remove()
}
})
```

But when the user disconnects after he wrote values to 'rooms', nothing happens. How can I remove the path written to when the user disconnects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onDisconnect()` doesn't make sense to use from Cloud Functions.  It makes sense on the client side, since the client is the thing doing the disconnecting.  If you want a function to trigger when the client disconnects, you'll have to set up the `onDisconnect()` on the client side, the have that write to a location that triggers a function to react to that event.

Comment: Hmm okay that seen reasonable... Actually, after looking in my database, the code did execute, but after 1 hour. That is weird, I tested it again and it removed it after 15 minutes after the client disconnected.

Comment: How does `onDisconnect()` not make sense from cloud functions?

Take this for example:
```promise(doSomething; onDisconnect().remove(); return ref;)
.then((ref) => dosomethingWithRef; do more onDisconnects() return someData).
then((data) return new Promise() { async code here resolve()})``` You can't do this without process.exit(); (which DOES call onDisconnect())

Comment: I second the comment above. It's really confusing for me not to have a way to know when the user disconnects from the server-side because it just means I can't trust the disconnecting process (since it comes from the client)

Comment: @HelderEsteves If have a feature request, you can send that to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  But the onDisconnect functionality is definitely only a function of the client SDKs right now.  You can write a cloud function to trigger on the data that an onDisconnect callback writes, but that's about it.