# How do I delete data from Firebase Realtime Database when a client loses connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am working on a game connect two players with firebase realtime databsee. but I want a way to can delete player data if lose his connection with the Internet.

Comment: Will using the OnDisconnect functionality work for you? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect you could update an "online" collection with a trigger that watches for the "disconnected" value.

Comment: That will only work with Cloud Functions as you cannot change anything without a connection..

Comment: @OneLunchMan That indeed sounds like the solution. Can you write it up in an answer? Possibly with some code snippets from the docs, and links to some previous answer such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/42825006, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30670928.

Answer (score 1):

This can be updated via the OnDisconnect method.

[This original answer from Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42825006/10747134) originally describes more details on the OnDisconnect method.

[Read more about the interface here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect).

You can set up a "connected presence" with [this Firebase example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) that uses the Realtime Database and Cloud Functions with OnDisconnect to show the status of a user.
Pulled from the example:

```
var userStatusDatabaseRef = firebase.database().ref('/status/' + uid);

firebase.database().ref('.info/connected').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    // If we're not currently connected, don't do anything.
    if (snapshot.val() == false) {
        return;
    };

    // If we are currently connected, then use the 'onDisconnect()'
    // method to add a set which will only trigger once this
    // client has disconnected by closing the app,
    // losing internet, or any other means.
    userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(function() {
        // The promise returned from .onDisconnect().set() will
        // resolve as soon as the server acknowledges the onDisconnect()
        // request, NOT once we've actually disconnected:
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect

        // We can now safely set ourselves as 'online' knowing that the
        // server will mark us as offline once we lose connection.
        userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
    });
});
```